# Pandas df MultiIndex returns different min/max using get_level_values() vs index[#]

Tags: pandas, datetime, max, min, multi-index

I have a df with a MultiIndex, and the 0 level is Datetime. Ran into the following:

```
df_fact.index.get_level_values(0).min()
Out[145]: Timestamp('2019-08-14 00:00:00')

df_fact.index.levels[0].min()
Out[146]: Timestamp('2018-09-10 00:00:00')

df_fact.index.get_level_values(0).max()
Out[147]: Timestamp('2019-11-11 23:45:00')

df_fact.index.levels[0].max()
Out[148]: Timestamp('2019-11-15 17:00:00')
```

Why the different outcomes? What am I missing?

Comment: Please provide a sample dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NM, figured it out. Leaving this here in case someone has the same silly question.

I had an df.xs slice operation upstream, reducing DatetimeIndex, which left unused level values, which are (confusingly) just called levels by the remove_unused_levels().

This fixed it:

```
df_fact.index = df_fact.index.remove_unused_levels()

df_fact.index.levels[0].min()
Out[193]: Timestamp('2019-08-14 00:00:00')
```

http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.remove_unused_levels.html